# why is the html table getting truncated when the email is sent?

Tags: python, html-email

I am trying to send an email constructing HTML code as shown in below code,the issue right now is the HTML table gets truncated when the email sent out (see the picture below) while if I create an HTML page out of the HTML code it looks fine, I am lost as to how to debug this? Any guidance on how to fix this?

```
def construct_html(gerrit_author_gerrit_url_age_dict, gerrit_author_count, merge_conflict_gerrits):
    logger.info("Constructing html...")
    icount = 1
    GerritMailBody = "<html><body><b><FONT COLOR=\"Maroon\">Hi,<br><br>Please find the list of pending Open Gerrit IDs in below projects </font><br><br> "
    GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + \
        "<table border=\"1\"><tr bgcolor=\"lightyellow\"><th>S.No</th><th>Owner</th><th>Count</th><th>GerritList/Age</th</tr>"

    for key in gerrit_author_count:
        logger.info('key %s' % key)
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<tr>"
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + str(icount) + "</td>"
        #GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + key.rstrip('\n') + "</td>"
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + \
            "name1" + str(icount) + "</td>"
        #GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + str(gerrit_author_count[key]) + "</td>"
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + \
            "name2" + str(icount) + "</td>"
        #GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + str(gerrit_author_gerrit_url_age_dict[key]) + "</td>"
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + \
            "name3" + str(icount) + "</td>"
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "</tr>"
        icount = icount + 1
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "</table>"
        GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + \
            "<br><br><i><b><FONT COLOR=\"NAVY\">Thanks and Regards,<br>WiFi DEV</i></b><br></body></html>"
    return GerritMailBody
```

EMAIL:

```
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ', '.join(receivers)
msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(cc)
#msg['Cc'] = cc
msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
try:
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('relay.company.com', 25)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
    msg.add_header('reply-to', REPLY_TO_ADDRESS)
    mail.sendmail(sender, receivers+cc, msg.as_string())
    logger.info('Email sent successfully %s %s'%(receivers,cc))
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('Problem sending email')
    logger.error('%s' % e)
```

HTML code:

```
<html>

<body><b>
        <FONT COLOR="Maroon">Hi,<br><br>Please find the list of pending Open Gerrit IDs in below projects </font>
        <br><br>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="lightyellow">
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>GerritList/Age</th</tr> <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>name11</td>
                <td>name21</td>
                <td>name31</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>name12</td>
                <td>name22</td>
                <td>name32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>name13</td>
                <td>name23</td>
                <td>name33</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>name14</td>
                <td>name24</td>
                <td>name34</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>name15</td>
                <td>name25</td>
                <td>name35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>name16</td>
                <td>name26</td>
                <td>name36</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>name17</td>
                <td>name27</td>
                <td>name37</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>name18</td>
                <td>name28</td>
                <td>name38</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>name19</td>
                <td>name29</td>
                <td>name39</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>name110</td>
                <td>name210</td>
                <td>name310</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>name111</td>
                <td>name211</td>
                <td>name311</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>name112</td>
                <td>name212</td>
                <td>name312</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>name113</td>
                <td>name213</td>
                <td>name313</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>name114</td>
                <td>name214</td>
                <td>name314</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>name115</td>
                <td>name215</td>
                <td>name315</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>name116</td>
                <td>name216</td>
                <td>name316</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>name117</td>
                <td>name217</td>
                <td>name317</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>name118</td>
                <td>name218</td>
                <td>name318</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>name119</td>
                <td>name219</td>
                <td>name319</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>name120</td>
                <td>name220</td>
                <td>name320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>name121</td>
                <td>name221</td>
                <td>name321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>name122</td>
                <td>name222</td>
                <td>name322</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>name123</td>
                <td>name223</td>
                <td>name323</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>name124</td>
                <td>name224</td>
                <td>name324</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>name125</td>
                <td>name225</td>
                <td>name325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>26</td>
                <td>name126</td>
                <td>name226</td>
                <td>name326</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>name127</td>
                <td>name227</td>
                <td>name327</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>name128</td>
                <td>name228</td>
                <td>name328</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>name129</td>
                <td>name229</td>
                <td>name329</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>name130</td>
                <td>name230</td>
                <td>name330</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>name131</td>
                <td>name231</td>
                <td>name331</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>name132</td>
                <td>name232</td>
                <td>name332</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>name133</td>
                <td>name233</td>
                <td>name333</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>name134</td>
                <td>name234</td>
                <td>name334</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>name135</td>
                <td>name235</td>
                <td>name335</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>name136</td>
                <td>name236</td>
                <td>name336</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>name137</td>
                <td>name237</td>
                <td>name337</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>name138</td>
                <td>name238</td>
                <td>name338</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>name139</td>
                <td>name239</td>
                <td>name339</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>name140</td>
                <td>name240</td>
                <td>name340</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>name141</td>
                <td>name241</td>
                <td>name341</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>name142</td>
                <td>name242</td>
                <td>name342</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>name143</td>
                <td>name243</td>
                <td>name343</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>name144</td>
                <td>name244</td>
                <td>name344</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>name145</td>
                <td>name245</td>
                <td>name345</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>name146</td>
                <td>name246</td>
                <td>name346</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>name147</td>
                <td>name247</td>
                <td>name347</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>name148</td>
                <td>name248</td>
                <td>name348</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>name149</td>
                <td>name249</td>
                <td>name349</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>name150</td>
                <td>name250</td>
                <td>name350</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>name151</td>
                <td>name251</td>
                <td>name351</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>name152</td>
                <td>name252</td>
                <td>name352</td>
            </tr>
        </table><br><br><i><b>
                <FONT COLOR="NAVY">Thanks and Regards,<br>WiFi DEV</i>
    </b><br></body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: It cuts off right at the 1000 character mark in your HTML, so I'm guessing that whatever client you're using to visualize this doesn't like super-long lines. Add some line breaks.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - add the linebreaks where

Comment: @user2125827: *"add the linebreaks where"*: At the end of every Row == `</tr>\n`